# Cannot read in Java data serialized in C++

Tags: java, c++, sockets, serialization

I have a Java client connected via socket to a C++ server.

The C++ server sends back to the client serialized objects.

However serialization works differently for Java and C++, so I cannot read the objects in that way:

```
objectInputStream.readObject();
```

This forces me to read each single value of the object manually:

```
byte[] buffer = read(FOUR_BYTES);
int flag = convertBufferToInt(buffer);

byte[] buffer = read(FOUR_BYTES);
float price = convertBufferToFloat(buffer);

// More stuff

myObject.setFlag(flag);
myObject.setPrice(price);

// More stuff
```

That's very hard to maintain. Isn't there an easier way to fill in my object with data?

Comment: Can you serialize/deserialize as XML ?

Comment: Never thought I would recommend it. Try Google Protocol Buffers, they have bindings both for Java and C++.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is (are). You have 2 options using only the standard library:

#### Using the [`DataInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) class

Check out the [`DataInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) class. It has methods to read values of primitive types like [`readByte()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readByte--), [`readInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readInt--), [`readLong()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLong--), [`readFloat()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readFloat--), [`readChar()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readChar--), [`readUTF()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readUTF--) (for reading UTF-8 encoded `String`) etc.

So your code becomes as simple as:

```
// Obtain InputStream from Socket:
InputStream is = ...;
// Create DataInputStream:
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);

myObject.setFlag(dis.readInt());
myObject.setPrice(dis.readFloat());
```

#### Using the [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) class

For this you have to read first the whole data into a byte array. Once you've done that, you can create a `ByteBuffer` using the [`ByteBuffer.wrap(byte[] array)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#wrap-byte:A-) method. The `ByteBuffer` class also supports reading primitive types just like the `DataInputStream` class.

The good thing about `ByteBuffer` that it supports changing the *byte order* (the order how the low and high bytes of a multi-byte value like `int` are read/written): [`ByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder bo)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order-java.nio.ByteOrder-). This is very useful if you're communicating with systems which use a differnet byte order (which might apply in your case).

Example using `ByteBuffer`:

```
// Read all your input data:
byte[] data = ...;
// Create ByteBuffer:
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);

myObject.setFlag(bb.getInt());
myObject.setPrice(bb.getFloat());
```

Answer (score 3):

To solve this in general you would need to write a C++ parser for objects serialized in Java. This is no small task.

Rather, I would recommend that you find some serialization format that is easy to parse and share between your Java and C++ programs. Preferably a format where there exists Java as well as C++ libraries for the serialization/deserialization. JSON or [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) are obvious candidates.